# How to use ampersand prefix with other arguments

Tags: ruby, proc

This is how I am reading my file:

```
raw = File.open(fname) { |f| f.read }
```

I thought I would take advantage of Ruby's shortcuts, such as the `&` operator to convert its argument to a proc. For example, one could use

```
nums = gets.split.map &:to_i   # get numbers from stdin
```

Instead of

```
nums = gets.split.map { |x| x.to_i }
```

So, I tried:

```
raw = File.open(fname) &:read
```

And I got the error:

```
path/to/file.rb:3:in `<main>': undefined method `&' for #<File:testing.txt> (NoMethodError)
```

It doesn't work with parentheses either (`raw = File.open(fname)(&:read)`).

How can I use this shortcut for opening a file? If I can't, then why not?

Comment: Huh, I did not know about this. Cool. Also, <insert medical joke here>.

Comment: Just a small clarification: I believe `:` is `to_proc`; `&` is proc-to_block.

Comment: @ Cary Swoveland `:` is part of a symbol literal. `&` is `to_proc` to block.

Comment: Don't get in the habit of trying to `read` files in production environments, unless you know for a fact they can never exceed the available RAM for your process, otherwise you'll take your machine to a crawl and your users and sysadmin will hunt you down. `read` "slurps" the file, which isn't a big advantage usually. And, as @sawa points out in the comments below, `File.read(fname)` is the right way to do this. What you're doing is not idiomatic and could lead to maintenance problems.

Comment: @sawa, thank you for setting me straight. I should have checked first.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try

```
raw = File.open(fname).read
```

Edit: The problem with this is that it doesn't close the file, as OP stated.

However this does work with ruby 1.9.3p448:

```
raw = File.open(fname, &:read)
```

This is just to demonstrate the use of the &/symbol representation of a block in ruby. As sawa points out, in actual practice one would ordinarily do:

```
raw = File.read(fname)
```

Comment: This does not close the file.

Comment: @Doorknob: You're right. However `raw = File.open(fname, &:read)` does work; not sure why it wasn't working for you. What version of ruby do you have?

Comment: Ah, apparently it does work. For some reason it wasn't when I tested it. Maybe a typo? Anyway, thanks!

Comment: The answer is okay, but a more concise way to open a file is `raw = File.read(fname)`.

Comment: @sawa Yes this should be stated in the answer for completeness. Thanks.